# Jquery ignore selector even if body is a selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have a little script that makes a little bottom mounted "quick menu" close when the user clicks anywhere on the page. I used `'body'` as the selector. However, I don't want it to close when the user clicks inside the menu (which is inside the div `foot`).

I've tried putting the selector as `'*'` then using `.not('.foot body')`, however that doesn't seem to solve anything. What are the chances I've actually typed the code wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('*').not('.foot body').click(function(){
      if($('.foot').hasClass('slide-up')) {
        $('.foot').addClass('slide-down', 1200, "easeOutQuad");
        $('.foot').removeClass('slide-up'); 
        $('.UP').text('Up ↑');
      } else {
      }
  });
});
```

**Edit**: It does work fine, and closes as it should, it's just the fact I don't want `.foot` to be able to close it

Comment: You're saying it shouldn't apply to `body` elements inside `.foot`. To specify both of them, comma separate them. Seems to me you only want to exclude `.foot`, so do `$('*').not('.foot').click()`

Comment: That's the strange thing, it still seems to happen when doing it the way you suggested. It's not a major issue, but it's just bugging me the fact it doesn't work! I tried to create a JSFiddle, but it wouldn't work properly so I had to give up with it

Comment: Ok, the other option is you bind to the entire document and check if the target you clicked has the foot class: `$(document).on('click', '*', function() { if($(this).hasClass('foot')) return false; // put the rest of your code here });`

Comment: Ah, yes, that's brilliant! Works perfectly, thank you

Comment: ^ Tried that, never got it to work so had to create a new question